# Are minor style edits ok?

Tags: discussion, edits

I find other people's edits to my writing style to be quite annoying. I wrote the question - it's my voice. I appreciate corrections and fixes but if you're just doing this:

[image: changing "Suppose I have some data" to "I have data",]

Then it feels like you're violating me in some indescribable way. The question wasn't a community wiki, in which case I think it would have been acceptable. Are we not supposed to have editorial control over our own questions here?

To be clear, I'm not saying the above style edit doesn't improve the flow (it's not the best example of what I'm talking about; just the most recent). What I am saying is that it is unwelcome. I didn't ask anyone for copy editing.

What is Stack Overflow's position on this?

Comment: Can't you simply reject or rollback the edit if you don't like it? Looking at just the small snippet in the image you included the sentence does seem to read/flow better with the change FWIW.

Comment: worth to note that it wasn't the only edit made to that question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61204267/revisions) so it's not only about style but the intention was to make the question *better*

Comment: "I didn't ask anyone for copy editing." No, but you submitted a question on a site that specifically *does* permit copy editing, and makes that clear from the start. The purpose of a question is to convey information, not to express artistic style. If an edit improves the readability of a question, it's entirely valid IMO. You could have a style of "I PREFER TO WRITE ALL IN CAPS" but many people find that harder to read - and I'd expect that to be either edited out, or for others to ask you to edit it yourself.

Comment: @Dave:  "To be clear, I'm not saying the above style edit doesn't improve the flow".

Comment: @JonSkeet Why aren't comments editable by other people then. For instance I could edit your comment to say "No, but you submitted a question *to* a site that --specifically-- does permit copy editing. --and makes that clear from the start--", etc. How would you feel about that?

Comment: Because comments are not first-class citizens, and you should not expect them to stay in  the site. They cannot be properly voted either.

Comment: "*What is Stackoverflow's position on this?*" posts are editable by anynbody, even people who don't have accounts. Furthermore, this is encouraged - having approved edits gives rep (at least to a generous cap) and beyond that edits can award you with a badge. With more rep you have, it becomes even easier is to make edits There is a whole section of SO dedicated to people who aren't the original poster editing posts. So, what do *you* think SO's stance is on whether users should make edits?

Comment: @VLAZ So because Stackoverflow allows and encourages edits you think it allows and encourages *all* edits? That seems unlikely.

Comment: You are right - edits that deface a post or harm it in any way are not encouraged. Very minor inconsequential edits are also frowned upon. Edits should improve a post. [Stack Overflow definitely embraces collaborative work on posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: Your rollback of constructive corrections as well as more stylistic edits is counterproductive. When someone edits your post to make it better, even if they include fixes that are not necessary, you should not *make it worse again* just to spite the editor. Roll it back and re-apply the necessary fixes, or edit the edited post to restore the original style, but don't just roll the entire thing back and leave it in a worse state than it was after the editor got there.

Comment: @trentcl I don't think they made it better, they were just trying to provoke me.

Comment: What an immature reaction.

Comment: Yes I agree but I can see how it might have amused him.

Comment: Admittedly, when I rolled it back again just now, that *was* partly to provoke you. But the comment was sincere.

Comment: *I don't think they made it better, they were just trying to provoke me.* It might have been worth mentioning in the question that it's the same person making these edits to your posts. It wouldn't have changed the answer much since you think your example is actually an improvement, but you might have gotten a little more understanding about feeling targeted if it was clear it's always the same user.

Answer (score 12):

This edit (and potentially a few other of similar nature) occurred in the [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) tag, which is thoroughly curated. Fortunately.

It's worth noting that although some of the changes might be perceived as unnecessary, they generally intend to improve readability and consistency across questions, using standard `rustfmt` formatting for code along with other improvements.

Very often, the editor in question is the top contributor to the tag, who also contributes greatly to duplicate question detection.

> What I am saying is that it is unwelcome. I didn't ask anyone for copy editing.

Remember that this isn't a discussion board or a blogging platform. The questions that you ask are not just for your benefit, but for every future visitor to the question. That is not only reflected in the content's licensing and the platform's capabilities, which allows anyone to suggest improvements like on Wikipedia; but in the guidance one can find in the help center and here in meta.

The edits you refer to were not detrimental to the post. But if you find edits that are, do roll them back.

However, in the event that the edit is an improvement —regardless of how minor— rejecting it is not particularly appreciated by those who are interested in enhancing the quality of the Q&A repository.

See also:

- [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/1233251)
- [What is the limit of editing others' posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102034) (SE)
- [Why can any user edit any other user's question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120576) (SE)
- [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) (Help Center)

Comment: Excellent performative demonstration of the principle, @yivi.